# Rotativa generating blank PDF in Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

We are using Rotativa in a .Net MVC 5 project. it works like a charm locally and fails (generates a blank PDF) equally when deployed to server. However, if I login to server and access the website as localhost it generates PDF just fine.

So it looked like a permission issue with which Application pool is running on. So, for testing purpose, I changed to run the App Pool to run on "Local System". Still same issue.

We have also tried:

1. "ViewasPDF"
2. App settings which looks like: `<add key="WkhtmltopdfPath" value="<path to the folder>"/>`

Below is the code:

```
return new ActionAsPdf("ActionMethod",new { id = id, partSelected =        part, selectedTab = selectedTab, isDownload = true })
{
    FileName = fileName,
    PageMargins = { Left = 0, Right = 0 },
    CustomSwitches = "--disable-external-links --disable-internal-links --disable-smart-shrinking --viewport-size 1600x900 --load-error-handling ignore",
    PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
    PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
    PageWidth = 210,
    PageHeight = 297
};
```

Comment: Is there any error message on the server?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have disabled displaying error with the custom switch --load-error-handling ignore. It might help to not have it disabled temporarily for the purpose of debugging.

Secondly, a blind guess from me is that you may have some images that require local path as src on the pdf? If that's the case you will need @Server.MapPath for each one of those.

For example:

```
<img src="@Server.MapPath("your image path")"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 var iResult = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("PrintForm", new { Id = Id }) { FileName = iFilename, SaveOnServerPath = ViewBag.FileName };
 iResult.UserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADUserID"].ToString();
 iResult.Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADPassword"].ToString();
 return iResult;
```

Here is a code example where aduser is user name and password, please create a  generic user account for this..